# Ошибка при обновлении проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Создал новый проект,в консоли получил следующее:

```
Gradle 'HelloWorld' project refresh failed
Error:Process 'command '/usr/lib/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

В гуггле увидел,что проблема может быть с java. Проверил:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Система-Ubuntu 16.04. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас в настройках проекта путь до jdk правильно задан?

Comment: Поковырявшись в гуггле тоже нашел упоминание про путь к jdk. Поставил переменную JAVA_HOME и проблема решилась(ide при запуске подхватила ее и  прописала себе путь к jdk от java 8).Ошибок нет,но вылез другой казус. Создал пустой активити, там в коде MainActivity есть строчка setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); На R. он ругается и говорит,что Cannot resolve sybol 'R'

Comment: R - автогенерируем. Если на него ругается, значит в проекте есть какие-то другие ошибки, которые не позволяют его сгенерить.

Comment: Да,вы правы.Есть еще ошибка=( Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Comment: Попробуйте даунгрейднуть Градл до этого http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip

Comment: даунгрейд не помог. проблема была в разрядности версии.у меня стоит убунта 32-битная.такие системы поддерживают максимум buildToolsVersion "23.0.1",но все равно спасибо за советы

Comment: Ну, то есть даунгрейднули.

Comment: да,что-то я напутал немного в понятиях. да,даунгрейднул версию сдк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решился заменой параметра buildToolsVersion с версии "25.0.0" на "23.0.1" в build.gradle файле. Проблема была в том,что разрядность моей текущей системы -32 бита.Данная разрядность поддерживает максимальную версию sdk = 23